# Is an odometer action on a product space always conjugate to its inverse by an involution?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

This is a follow on question from
[Is an non-singualr invertable ergodic transformation on a measure space isomorphic to its inverse?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/165058/is-an-non-singualr-invertable-ergodic-transformation-on-a-measure-space-isomorph)

Given a measure $\mu$ on the product space $X = \prod_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb Z_{l(i)}, l(i) \in \mathbb Z^+$ and the adic odometer action $T$, it seems to me that $T$ is always conjugate to its inverse $T^{-1}$ via the involution $\phi$ which acts on $x\in X$ defined by
$$ \phi(x)_i = l(i) - 1 - x_i, i \in \mathbb Z^+$$
Since $\phi$ maps cylinders to cylinders, $\mu\circ \phi$ is an equivalent measure to $\mu$.

For example, if $l(i) = 2$ and $x = 111101\cdots$ then
$$ T^{-1}(\phi(x)) = T^{-1}(000010\cdots) = 111100\cdots = \phi(000011\cdots) = \phi(Tx) $$

> Question 1:  $T$ is conjuagte to $T^{-1}$ via an involution iff $T$ can be expressed as a combination of two involutions. How to you express the adic odometer action as a combination of two involutions?
>
> Question 2: can the involutions from question 1 be used when $X$ is a Bratteli-Vershik diagram.

Comment: What am I missing? If $T^{-1}\phi=\phi T$, then $\phi T$ is another involution as $\phi T\phi T=\phi T T^{-1}\phi =\phi^2=\text{id}$. Now $T=\phi\circ(\phi \circ T)$ et voilà?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand Q2; but there is a simple method using the Vershik map. The odometer can be realized on the Bratteli diagram which consists of one vertex at each level and $l(i)$ edges from the $i$th level; the Vershik map is implemented by the lex ordering (although it doesn't matter for this B-diagram!) from left to right; the inverse transformation is implemented by reversing the ordering at each level (that is, right to left), yielding the intertwining homeomorphism, which in this case is an involution ... but this is so easy, I may have misunderstood the question.

Comment: For Q2 I mean a Bratteli diagram with more than one vertex at each level. I wish to distinguish between reversing the ordering and the map $\phi$ defined in the question. 1) reversing the order of the B-diagram. Let $\psi : (V,E,\leq) \mapsto (V,E,\geq), \phi(x) = x$. In this case the action of $T$ and $T^{-1}$ are the same and $\frac{dT^{-1}\mu}{d\mu} = \frac{dT\mu}{d\mu}$ 2) The map $\phi : (V,E,\leq) \mapsto (V,E,\leq)$ does not change the order, and the action of $T$ and $T^{-1}$ are different, the derivatives are not necessarily the same.